# Slim framework Message: Callable Homecontroller does not exist

Tags: php, routes, slim

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSTfN.png)

---

**public/index.php**

```
<?php


require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli-server') {
    // To help the built-in PHP dev server, check if the request was actually for
    // something which should probably be served as a static file
    $url  = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}



session_start();

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';



$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';

// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';

// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

---

**Here we have the composer.json**

```
{

"autoload":{
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src"
    }
},

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "slim/slim": "^3.1",
    "slim/php-view": "^2.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "illuminate/database": "~5.1",
    "slim/twig-view": "^2.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": ">=4.8 < 6.0"
},

"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout" : 0
},
}
```

---

**Here is my controller, i obtain a error with the namespace and in all the examples that i have seen use this so.. I don't know what to do more**

```
<?php

namespace \App\Controllers;

class Homecontroller
{
    protected $container;

    // constructor receives container instance
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        echo "locura";
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
    }

    public function contact($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

---

*Actual configuration*
**In my routes.php I have put this:**

```
$app->get('/new', \Homecontroller::class . ':home');
```

---

*Before configuration*

In the above code, I tried to create the controller into the container, and then use

```
$app->get('/new', '\HomeController:home');
```

And in the dependencies.php I put this code:

```
$container['HomeController'] = function($c) {
$view = $c->get("view"); // retrieve the 'view' from the container
return new HomeController($view);
```

};

but I didn't obtain any result with any configuration

---

I would like to load the HomeController from router

This is the error that I have when I put **api.powertv/new**

```
 Type: RuntimeException
 Message: Callable Homecontroller does not exist
File:       /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
Line: 90
```

i come here, and I put this post like my last resource, if this fails I don't know what I am going to do.

Comment: if u are referring to the controllers directory, the relative path is: src/controllers. How do I exactly add another line?

Comment: i am greatflul that u tried to help me, but It doesn't work :(

Comment: Read this section of composer documentation https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap I guess it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the source. I am going to read it :)

Comment: Pay attention to upper and lower case. `Homecontroller` vs. `HomeController`.

Comment: If somebody have this problem, Check for typo errors , i had similar problem and found out `Controllers` is mistyped `Contorllers` in folder name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use absolute namespace path in your:

1. dependencies.php

   ```
    $container['yourController'] = function ($c) {
     $view = $c['view'];
     return new \App\Controllers\YourController($view);
   }
   ```
2. routes.php

   ```
     $app->get('your_defined_route_name', \App\Controllers\YourController::class . ':YourControllerMethod');
   ```

Comment: Its the first time that I obtain another error, in the browser: Type: Error
Message: Undefined constant 'App\controllers'
File: /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/src/Controllers/HomeController.php
Line: 5.   That constant is the namespace, so I suppose that now I have to modify the composer.json ?? but how?

Comment: the compose.json was good, if I put this in routes.php $app->get('/new', '\App\controllers\HomeController:home'); and in home controller in line 3 this: namespace App\controllers;  It works for me, thanks man. The problem, was that the namespace was in line 5, not in 3.

Answer (score 0):

The name inside the container and thoose who you use in the route *must* match
You've been set the container key to `HomeController` and used `\HomeController` in the route, these strings are not equal.

either self create the strings

```
$container['HomeController'] = function($c) {
    $view = $c->get("view"); // retrieve the 'view' from the container
    return new HomeController($view);
};
$app->get('/new', 'HomeController:home');
```

or use the `::class` syntax for both:

```
$container[HomeController::class] = function($c) {
    $view = $c->get("view"); // retrieve the 'view' from the container
    return new HomeController($view);
};
$app->get('/new', [HomeController::class, 'home');
// or $app->get('/new', HomeController::class . ':home');
```

Comment: i have tried the 2 options and doesn't work, I obtain this error:    Type: Error
Message: Class 'HomeController' not found
File: /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/src/dependencies.php
Line: 52
i have also to say that in the HomeController when I am developing with php storm the namespace gives me the next error: undefined constant Controllers. Maybe I have the error here.

Answer (score 0):

with the answer of Pheara I obtain another error, is the next:

```
Type: Error
Message: Undefined constant 'App\controllers'
File:/Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/src/Controllers/HomeController.php
Line: 5
```

---

**the trace of the error is the next:**

```
 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444):   include()
#1  /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322):   Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Users/alfonso/...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader- >loadClass('App\\Controllers...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\Controllers...')
#4 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(89): class_exists('App\\Controllers...')
#5 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(67): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveCallable('App\\Controllers...')
#6 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolverAwareTrait.php(45): Slim\CallableResolver->resolve('App\\Controllers...')
#7 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(330): Slim\Routable->resolveCallable('App\\Controllers...')
#8 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(313): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#10 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(495): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#11 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#12 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(388): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#13 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(296): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#14 /Users/alfonso/Sites/powertv_api/public/index.php(39): Slim\App->run()
#15 {main}
```

---

For solve this error you have to put the namespace in the 3 line:

```
<?php 

namespace [yournamespace]

//rest of your controller
```