# Access Controller From Route In Slim

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I have Some Routes On \src\routes.php

```
$app->get('/coba', 'App\controllers\HomeController:getfromcontroller');
```

And in myapp/app/controllers/HomeController.php like this

```
public function getfromcontroller((Request $request, Response $response){
     $response->withStatus(200)->write('Hello Motehr!');
}
```

and if i'am access http://localhost/myapp/public/coba thats errror

> Type: RuntimeException Message: Callable
>   App\controllers\HomeController does not exist File:
>   C:\laragon\www\depoapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php
>   Line: 90

Comment: Do you have an autoloader or do you include your class files manually?

Comment: of courese on index.php 

require  __DIR__ . '/../app/controllers/HomeController.php';

Comment: Better include the composer autoloader.

Comment: Do other controllers work as expected? I think this problem is not caused by these parts of code in the question, it is probably a problem with namespaces and the autoloader. So, can you please add the part of `HomeController.php` that you're defining the namespace and class name? And also can you add the `autoload` part of `composer.json`?

Comment: Ensure that `HomeController` is in the `App\controllers` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to call the correct namespace:

```
$app->get('/coba', ['**YOURAPP**\App\controllers\HomeController', 'getfromcontroller']);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are three things that can happen here.

1. Are all your URLs being redirected to the index.php in your public folder? in your case

   myapp/public.index.php
2. Make sure you rename your controller folder to Controller and ensure your function is in the controller class.
3. Try the solution in question [47724219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724219/slim-framework-message-callable-homecontroller-does-not-exist) where you have to use the absolute namespace.